# Transparent text inside non-transparent div

Tags: html, css

I have a background image, and a white div on top of it. I want to have text inside that div that is transparent, so that you can see "through" to the background image. Is that at all possible?

Should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Use the `opacity` attribute

Comment: You can get close but it seems like it's a webkit only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pHCsF/. You may be better off just creating the full image.

Comment: How would this be achieved using canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this for your text in `CSS`

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS property on your white div to make the underlying image show through.

```
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
```

Comment: No, the div should be opaque, but the text transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of text, just use a GIF image that has pixel "wholes" (text has no pixels, pixels surround it). That is probably a solution with highest compatibility.