# CSS3 - Transparent text through `div`?

Tags: css

I was looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523557/transparent-text-inside-non-transparent-div).
But when I tried it, it won't work.

The text is transparent, but not through the div, which is the big idea.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U876C/)

```
.title1_background {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 8%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.title1_background h1 {
    font-size: 400%;
    display: block;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML/CSS: "See Through Background" Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957082/html-css-see-through-background-text)

Comment: no luck with firefox but working in chrome http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageUnderText/

Comment: @Mr.Alien I actually linked it to my question.  I tried it but couldn't get it working. That's what this question is about

Comment: @Claudio the question I've linked is a different one, there are two properties to be used, you are using a single property

Comment: Oh, sorry. Didn't look that closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way is to **use two images**.

The **background image** and the **image with hollow text above** it.

You can achieve the same using `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` but this would only work with browsers supporting `-webkit`.

see this **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pHCsF/)** it works fine in `chrome` since it supports `-webkit` but won't work in `firefox`.

**[See](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp)** the browsers and their versions that support `-webkit`

We should always prefer to design and develop that supports **cross browser compatibility**.

Comment: This fiddle is not yours - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523557/transparent-text-inside-non-transparent-div#comment27240865_18523557 If it is the same question, consider flagging the question as a duplicate

Comment: yeah i used that fiddle to just demonstrate a comparison. Will consider flagging from the next time. Thanks @BoltClock

Answer (score 0):

Try This [***link***](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pHCsF/)

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#outer {
width:300px;
height:300px;
background-image: url(http://www.placekitten.com/300/300);
overflow:auto;
 }
#wrapper {
background: #fff;
margin: 100px 0;
opacity:0.6;
}
#inner {
font: bold 60px Arial;
text-align:center;
margin:20px;
background-color: #fff;
background-image: url(http://www.placekitten.com/300/300);
background-position: 280px 201px;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
#outer:hover{
border:solid 2px #4072B4;
}
```

Comment: This fiddle is not yours - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523557/transparent-text-inside-non-transparent-div#comment27240865_18523557 If it is the same question, consider flagging the question as a duplicate